# Using gruntjs in a web service

Tags: gruntjs

I wonder if it would be possible to send some files to a web service that would run grunt tasks against these files so that instead of many people have to put grunt inside their project, they could push an archive of their project to this web service.

Thanks for any response or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could work in theory. But don't know of any such service.

But that would require you to have different gruntfiles for different branches and you need to update that gruntfile if your build process changes over time. It is better to have this as a part of your project.

You would anyway need a way to automate sending it to the service. Which is the whole point of grunt, task automation. I recommend just having it in your project. This have been done for years with makefiles, rakefiles etc.